# What does it cost to make a contract through Tezos?

Tags: baking, smart-contracts

I have seen clear structure and numbers on how baking, delegating and double endorsing etc. affect to the users amount of Tezos, but is there any cost on making a contract (in other words creating content stored in the block chain)? And is the flow into your wallet or out of it?

If baking gives you money, how about the gist (contracts) that feed the baking process and make the result thus bigger? (sorry baking metaphora extension)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contract origination incurs standard transaction fees (see [here](https://github.com/TezTech/eztz/blob/master/PROTO_003_FEES.md)). One thing to note is that the storage cost is 0.001 tez per byte of data being stored on-chain (which includes the size of your contract and initial bytes for the state/storage data of the contract.

Contract calls, which are just transactions to a smart contract, may incur storage costs IF the transaction increases the state/storage data (e.g. adding an additional element to a map).